# Blender error – T67350,T52572 CUDA error

Tags: rendering, error

This problem that occurs when we use rendering engine Cycles.

The error states as:

```
CUDA error: Illegal address
CUDA Error – Failed to create CUDA context.
```

The error occurs during rendering preview, as well as during rendering itself.

It doesn't even matter how complex the rendered scene is. The error pops up with the basic cube.

Tried and tested combinations for rendering:

- FULL HD_House_scene

  3 cards : time: **43 sec** (without GPU no. 2)

  active GPU for render --- 1.3.4**
- Full HD_House_scene_ test – separately on one card

  1 Card (GPU1) ---- 1:26.81 sec

  1 Card (GPU3) ---- 1:25:97 sec

  1 Card (GPU4) ---- 1:25.82 sec

  **1 Card (GPU2) --- ERROR**

Three cards render without any trouble in similar time lapses.
So, the problem always occurs when the GPU no. 2 is active separately or combined with any other GPU.

But if we render in Octane or Vray, they seem to be working just fine.

Furthermore, the error occurred after about a month and not a thing has been changed. Before, everything worked perfectly fine.

The error remains even after complete re-installing of the Windows and and the update of the BIOS.

Also tried:

- Uninstalling and re-installing of all Nvidia programmes and drivers alongside with Cuda (separately).
- Complete re-installing of the Blender and trying various versions of the software → 2.83. 2.9, 2.93. 3.0, 3.01. 3.12 → The problem and the error at the GPU no. 2 always stays the same.
- We also tried adding some delay on restart of the graphic driver into registers → the error with the GPU no. 2 stays the same. But it seems to us that other GPU’s render at a faster pace alongside the error.

→ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6VW0KgCv4o

GPU’s 1, 3 and 4 are all connected in the same way and the GPU no. 2 is connected via PHANTEKS extending cabel on riser – 60 cm (manufacturer no. PH-CBRS_PR60)

PC specifications:
Motherboard ASRock TRX40 Creator / AMD TRX40 / 8x DDR4 / SATA III / USB / 10GLAN / M.2 / sc.sTRX4 / Wi-Fi / ATX

Processor AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3960X (24 cores, 48 threads, 3.8 GHz (TDP 280W), Boost 4.5 GHz, 128MB L3 cache, socket AMD TRX4, Castle Peak, no cooling)

4×GPU:

MSI NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti, 10240 CUDA PCIe x16 4.0, 1× HDMI, 3× DisplayPort, 12GB GDDR6X, 384bit memory bus, frequency 1665 MHz (boost), active cooling

Could you be able to help us in finding and solving the problem?

Comment: I would suggest your company to ask their trusted IT service provider to discuss the problem on hardware side.

Comment: "*Could you be able to help us in finding and solving the problem, please?*" This is something that is highly unlikely any of us could do remotely over the internet without access to the hardware